# Best way to record date with mandatory year and month, and only optional day

Tags: php, sql, date, datetime, laravel

I am building a php/sql (Laravel) app for managing magazines. Each magazine has a property of date of issue. Unfortunately, this date may be either in the format of `year-month-day` or `year-month` for monthly periodicals. When retrieving a magazine, I need to get its date of issue as is, meaning `year-month` only for monthlies, and `year-month-day` for the rest.

The only solution that I can think of is add another column of `boolean` type, for example `is_monthly`, and use that to determine the issue date format. But I would like to know if there is a better way to store date in a database as only year and month, without a day.

Comment: Maybe just 3 columns year, month, day(nullable). Then build result as concatenation of them

Comment: Store as a full date. add the first day of month 01 for those without a day and have a type field for Frequency.  Use frequency to determine if the 01 is relevant. extract month/year when needed, or full date when needed based on frequency though a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store as 3 columns (year/month/date):

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cccd0/3/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE magazine(title VARCHAR(100), `year` INT NOT NULL,
                      month TINYINT NOT NULL, day TINYINT NULL);

INSERT INTO magazine
VALUES ('aaa', 2015, 10, 16), ('bbb', 2015, 11, NULL);

SELECT 
    title,
    CASE WHEN day IS NULL THEN CONCAT(`year`, '-' , month)
         ELSE CONCAT(`year`, '-' , month, '-', day)
     END AS `publish_date`
FROM magazine
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╗
║ title  ║ publish_date ║
╠════════╬══════════════╣
║ aaa    ║ 2015-10-16   ║
║ bbb    ║ 2015-11      ║
╚════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: All three answers were very useful, so it made it really hard to decide which one to use. In the end I opted for this one. There is nothing wrong with the other two either.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd prefer going with your approach of having a `boolean` column say `is_monthly` as it would give you greater control over your approach in the long run.

You can set your `date` as a [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) instance and define a mutator say `setIssueDateAttribute($date)` in your model and default the day part of your date to say the first of the month in case there is no day value available, i.e. in case `is_monthly` is set to `true`.

This way, you would be able to simply store the date as is in the database without any hassle and when you wish to display only the month and the year of the date, you could put it as

```
$this->attributes['issue_date'] = Carbon::setToStringFormat('F, Y');
```

in your `getIssueDateAttribute($date) accessor.

You can find more about setting attributes here:

[Laravel Tutorial on Dates, Scope and Mutators](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11)

[Accessors and Mutators Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, then it supports incomplete dates as part of the date datatype.  This might solve your problem.

However, I might suggest that you store the date-of-issue as a string representation of the date.  I imagine that this could vary by magazine.  Then use a date to store the "functional" date, used for calculations.  The functional date could just use a canonical day-of-the-month (such as "1") for the issue date.